# Get specific item from object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections

I'm attempting to return the specific hospital name associated to a patient but keep getting errors.

```
Models:
Hospital
has_many :patients

Patients
belong_to :hospital
```

When rendering my page I call the controller:

```
def list_patients
      @patients = Patient.all
  end
```

In my view I print out each patient and their information:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><%= patient.first_name + "," + patient.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= patient.ssn %></td>
        <td><%= patient.dob %></td>
        <td><%= patient.hospital.name%></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

The above returns an "undefined method for name".  If I remove name I can see that a object `(<Hospital:0x007fa1d9530138>)`
 is returned, but I'm unable to then access the specific attributes within the object.

I can return the specific hospital ID, if I do something like:

```
patient.hospital_id
```

but am then stuck on how to get to the hospital name.

Comment: if a patient only belongs to one hospital. how can you get collection or array.? `patient.hospital` should return ab object.  im supposing that there is hospital_id in patients table this is how your assosiation describes

Comment: there is a hospital_id, but I'm confused on how to then retrieve the name associated to that id from my hospital table

Comment: so. hospital_id is the foreign_key in patient table. which is used to query hospital tables to fetch details. when you do patient.hospital and if it returns you hospital object. then this is similar to when you have patient. just like when you have patient object and you can fetch patient.last_name. similarly if you have patient.hospital to be hospital object. you can fetch patient.hospital.name.

Comment: Is "name" an accesible attribute in the 'Hospital' model?

Comment: okay try this. go to your rails console using `rails c` and then type this `Patient.first.hospital` what does it return.? hospital object.?

Comment: thanks.  I had a nil in the hospital_id column and wasn't checking for them.  much appreciated.

Comment: So the error was actually `"undefined method name for nil"`...

Answer (score 0):

Is your code equal to the pasted one?

If so, is `belongs_to` and not `belong_to`

If you also can't do `Hospital.first.patients` in the console, make sure you have a `hospital_id` in you patient model